# Running pytest with cython - how to compile cython modules in pytest?

Tags: python, testing, cython, pytest

I have a project organized as follows:

```
project
├── project
│   ├── module1
│   │   ├── api.py
│   │   ├── _cpython_foo.py
│   │   └── _cython_foo.pyx
│   └── module2
├── setup.py
└── tests
    └── module1
        ├── test_cython_foo.py
        └── test_cpython_foo.py
```

where `api.py` imports cythonized extensions:

```
 """api.py""""
 from _cython_foo import cython_fun
```

My setup script builds the `.pyx` source inplace correctly and I'm able to use `cython_fun` in the installed package:

```
import project.module1.api as module1
module1.cython_fun()    # OK
```

However, `pytest` complains that it cannot import the cython module since the compiled binaries are not in place until I invoke setup.

```
project/module1/api.py:2: in <module>
    from _cython_foo import cython_fun
E   ImportError: No module named _cython_foo
```

It seems like bad style to leave a bunch of precompiled binaries inside my project directory that pytest depends on, so is there a conventional way to have pytest temporarily build the cython modules for the purpose of my unit tests only?

Comment: You could install `pytest-runner` and invoke `python setup.py pytest`, or install the package in editable mode in a virtualenv and run the tests from there (`python setup.py develop` or even better, `pip install --editable project/`).

Comment: @hoefling Ah, pytest-runner seems to do what I need. If you can write your reply as a short formal answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Why not let cython build the binaries before running the tests? not sure I'm seeing any bad style there, what would exactly be the issue in doing that while in development mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know about two ways of marrying `pytest` with cythonized extensions:

1. Do not invoke the tests via `pytest` directly; instead, use in-place test command with the setup script. To do that, install `pytest-runner` plugin that adds a `pytest` command:

   ```
   $ pip install pytest-runner
   ```

   Now you should be able to invoke the tests with `pytest` by issuing

   ```
   $ python setup.py pytest
   ```

   This approach, however, will require some changes in the way the command line args are passed: the pendant to command

   ```
   $ pytest --arg1 --arg2
   ```

   will be

   ```
   $ python setup.py pytest --addopts "--arg1 --arg2"
   ```
2. If you want to continue using the `pytest` command: install the project in development mode (ideally, in a [virtualenv](/questions/tagged/virtualenv)).

   ```
   (myenv) $ pip install --editable dir/
   ```

   where `dir/` is the directory containing the `setup.py` script. Now the extensions will be prebuilt and `pytest` will be able to resolve them.