# How to use Cython with pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, pycharm, cython, pytest

The goal is to use the `pytest` unit test framework for a Python3 project that uses Cython. This is not a plug-and-play thing, because `pytest` by default is not able to import the Cython modules.

**One unsuccessful solution** would be to use the [**`pytest-cython`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-cython) plugin, but it simply does not work for me:

```
> py.test --doctest-cython
usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --doctest-cython
  inifile: None
  rootdir: /censored/path/to/my/project/dir
```

To verify that I have the package installed:

```
> pip freeze | grep pytest-cython
pytest-cython==0.1.0
```

**UPDATE**:
I'm using PyCharm and it seems that it is not using my pip-installed packages but rather uses a custom(?) pycharm repository for packages used by my project. Once I added `pytest-cython` to that repository, the command runs but strange enough it doesn't recognize the Cython module anyway, although the package/add-on is specifically designed for that purpose:

```
> pytest --doctest-cython
Traceback:
tests/test_prism.py:2: in <module>
    from cpc_naive.prism import readSequence, processInput
cpc_naive/prism.py:5: in <module>
    from calculateScore import calculateScore, filterSortAlphas, 
calculateAlphaMatrix_c#, incrementOverlapRanges  # cython code
E   ImportError: No module named 'calculateScore'
```

**Another unsuccessful solution** I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330471/running-pytest-with-cython-how-to-compile-cython-modules-in-pytest) is to use **`pytest-runner`**, but this yields:

```
> python3 setup.py pytest
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'pytest'
```

**UPDATE**:

I first had forgotten to add `setup_requires=['pytest-runner', ...]` and `tests_require=['pytest', ...]` to the setup script. Once i did that, I got another error:

```
> python3 setup.py pytest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 42, in <module>
    tests_require=['pytest']
(...)
AttributeError: type object 'test' has no attribute 'install_dists'
```

**UPDATE 2 (setup.py)**:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

from setuptools import find_packages
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

try:  # try to build the .c file
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
except ImportError:  # if the end-user doesn't have Cython that's OK; you should have shipped the .c files anyway.
    use_cython = False
else:
    use_cython = True

cmdclass = {}
ext_modules = []

if use_cython:
    ext_modules += [
        Extension("cpc_naive.calculateScore", ["cpc_naive/calculateScore.pyx"],
                  extra_compile_args=['-g'],   # -g for debugging
                  define_macros=[('CYTHON_TRACE', '1')]),
    ]
    cmdclass.update({'build_ext': build_ext})
else:
    ext_modules += [
        Extension("cpc_naive.calculateScore", ["cpc_naive/calculateScore.c"],
                  define_macros=[('CYTHON_TRACE', '1')]),  # compiled C files are stored in /home/pdiracdelta/.pyxbld/
    ]

setup(
    name='cpc_naive',
    author=censored,
    author_email=censored,
    license=censored,
    packages=find_packages(),
    cmdclass=cmdclass,
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    install_requires=['Cython', 'numpy'],
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner'],
    tests_require=['pytest']
)
```

**UPDATE 3 (partial fix)**:
As suggested by @hoefling I downgraded `pytest-runner` to a version <4 (in fact 3.0.1) and this resolves the error in update 1, but now I get the same Exception as with the `pytest-cython` solution:

```
E   ImportError: No module named 'calculateScore'
```

It just doesn't seem to recognize the module. Perhaps this is due to some absolute/relative import mojo I don't understand.

How can I use `pytest` with Cython? How can I discover why these methods aren't working and then fix it?

**FINAL UPDATE**:
After taking both the original problem and the question Updates into consideration (thanks @hoefling for solving these issues!), this question is now reduced to the question of:

> why can pytest no import the Cython module calculateScore, even though running the code just with python (no pytest) works just fine?

Comment: Are you testing functions that are only accessible from within the `cython` module (`cdef`), or just functions that can be accessed from the calling Python (`cpdef`, `def`)?

Comment: If the `pytest` command does not show up, you may have installed `pytest-runner`  with the wrong `pip` - does `pip` refer to your `python3` installation? Check what `pip -V` yields, probably it refers to `python2`. If this is the case, check if you have `pip3` available and install `pytest-runner` for `python3` with `pip3 install pytest-runner`.

Comment: Also is your cython code written in such a way that it gets compiled automatically be a setup.py file? It sounds vaguely like you're trying to build the C extensions manually.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm using `def`

Comment: @hoefling It is installed with pip3 as well, I have both.

Comment: @ngoldbaum yes, the cython is compiled automatically using ext_moduels.

Comment: I updated the problem description as I got a step further with both pytest-runner and pytest-cython.

Comment: @PDiracDelta post your complete setup script. The stack trace you posted does not help, unfortunately.

Comment: @hoefling Here you go. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: The `setup.py` looks fine to me. Guess: your installed `pytest` version is not compatible with `pytest-runner` version. What versions do you use? Most probably you have `pytest-runner>=3` installed and some pre-3.0 `pytest`, they are incompatible. Either update `pytest` to >3 (`tests_require=['pytest>3']`), or downgrade `pytest-runner` (`setup_requires=['pytest-runner<3']`).

Comment: @hoefling pytest: alas, pytest: 3.4.1; pytest-runner: 4.0. So I'm guessing you're out of ideas too now? :/

Comment: Then you probably experience [this bug](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-runner/issues/39). Downgrade `pytest-runner` to <4 as suggested in the issue comments.

Comment: Thanks @hoefling ! That seems to have solved the main issue!
I now get the same Exception as with the `pytest-cython` solution, which seems that it still fails to import. It just doesn't seem to recognize/find the module. Perhaps this is due to some absolute/relative import mojo I don't understand (even though it imports just fine when I run my main cpc_naive.prism module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @hoefling suggested, one should use `pytest-runner` version <0.4 to avoid the

```
AttributeError: type object 'test' has no attribute 'install_dists'
```

To then answer the actual and final question (in addition to partial, off-topic, user-specific fixes added to the question post itself) of why `pytest` cannot import the Cython module `calculateScore`, even though running the code just with python (no pytest) works just fine:
that remaining issue is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49068162/pytest-cannot-find-module-on-import-but-code-runs-just-fine/49068163#49068163).