# pytest cannot find module on import but code runs just fine

Tags: python-3.x, cython, pytest

The goal is to use the pytest unit test framework for a Python3 project that uses Cython. This is not a plug-and-play thing, because pytest by default is not able to import the Cython modules. Namely, I get the following error when importing from a Cython .pyx module, in my case named 'calculateScore':

```
package/mainmodule.py:5: in <module>
    from calculateScore import some_functions
E   ImportError: No module named 'calculateScore'
```

This problem occurs both when using the [pytest-runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330471/running-pytest-with-cython-how-to-compile-cython-modules-in-pytest) as well as the [pytest-cython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-cython) approach. Strangely enough, the code runs just fine as a python application when you're not trying to test it using `pytest`.
Changing the import style to `import calculateScore` or `import package.calculateScore` does not help.

Comment: The problem may be related to this issue: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1769#issuecomment-440312854
Try setting the linetrace=True C compiler directive in your .pyx file

Comment: Well, running pytest over a codebase with cython using latest versions of everything (and cython 3.0.8) and pytest manages just fine (just had to tell pytest to ignore a .py source having a .pxd building cython for it, but tests code running the ensuing cython module seamlessly imported the built module without any hickup). Of course, integrating cython with pytest and living with imperfect IDE support as of adding cython to a project takes some work, which one should contemplate the future maintenance complexity of and how well others will manage with it all.

Comment: Disclaimer: there are many ways to use cython in a project, and in mine where pytest manages loading cythonized modules just fine, I am not currently using `.pyx` but rather a `.py` clean of cython side by side to a `.pxd` which weakly auto-cythonizes the functions included in the `.py` as well as introduces cython implementations for other functions ― which works fine for me ― the resulting cython modules are seamlessly loaded by tests run by pytest.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why this is happening, but for me the easiest solution was to use the **`pytest-cython`** approach and change one or multiple things listed below in the package's `setup.py` file:

- when defining your `Extension` for the `ext_modules` to include the Cython `.pyx` files, do *not* use `distutils.extension.Extension` but rather use **`setuptools.Extension`**

The reason why I manually create an `Extension` instead of using the `Cython.Build.cythonize` function, is not important here. But please note that for the **`pytest-runner`** approach:

- do *not* use the `cythonize` function, but create the Extension manually

After writing this post I cannot even seem to reproduce the problem using `pytest-cython` anymore, which suggests that maybe something else is the cause of the problem. An additional thing you could try is to make sure that:

- when manually creating an `Extension` for your `.pyx` module, make sure the name of the `Extension` is identical to the name of the module (so name it 'calculateScore' and *not* for instance 'package.calculateScore').
- delete the compiled `.so` file corresponding to your `.pyx` file and then re-run.

Comment: But why is this necessary? Is this a Pytest bug? I came here looking for *what is actually going on*, and I only got more questions...

Comment: No idea, sorry :/